# Add commas to numbers in CrossTable with Pander

Tags: r, knitr, pander

I would like to add commas to numbers produced in CrossTable using pander.  According to the pander::pander.CrossTable, options can be passed to pandoc.table and there is an option called "big.mark" to add commas.  But the following does not work:

```
require(pander)
require(descr)
panderOptions("big.mark", ",")
t1<-c(rep("a",1500),rep("b",1000))
t2<-c(rep("b",1200),rep("a",300), rep("c", 1000))
pander(CrossTable(t1,t2, prop.r=TRUE,  prop.c=FALSE, prop.t=FALSE, expected=FALSE, prop.chisq=FALSE, big.mark=panderOptions("big.mark")))

------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;\    t2\     &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\ 
   t1        a         b         c       Total  
--------- -------- --------- --------- ---------
 **a**\   &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\      300\     1200\      0\       1500\   
 Row(%)     20%       80%       0%        60%   

 **b**\   &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\       0\       0\       1000\     1000\   
 Row(%)      0%       0%       100%       40%   

  Total     300      1200      1000      2500   
------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas on how I can add commas to the counts above? Thanks

Comment: This is a bug in [`pander.CrossTable`](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/S3.R#L904) -- I will try to fix that soon, but pull requests are also welcommed.